# Garbled fonts in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, resharper

I'm using for the time being an old VS 2005. Fonts appear to be messed up at times (see display in link below); this seems to be happening all the time with Resharper switched on but I have also seen it without Resharper being activated (typically on a line throwing an exception while debugging) although not so frequently. Would anyone know what's going on ?

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f1c297c987.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Is your monitor really that small?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is install VS2005 SP1, it worked for me. See: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-181618?query=in%3A+Resharper#content-tab=0